# Using IF AND and multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need to create a formula to identify the tier based on the following conditions:

1. Result   Conditon1     Condition2
2. tier_1    >=61          >=300001
3. tier_2    >=25 - <=60   >=100001 - <=300000
4. tier_3    <=24          >=0 - <=100000

I have created individual formulas but I can't put them together

```
=if(and(B19>=61,B1823>=300001),"Tier 1")

=IF(and(B18>=100001,B18<=300000,B19>=25,B19<=60),"Tier 2")

=if(and(B19>=0,B19<=100000,B18<=24),"Tier 3")
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the Excel `IF` function is:

```
=IF(some_condition, "true", "false")
```

You may nest your current `IF` calls to get the desired logic:

```
=IF(AND(B19 >= 61, B1823 >= 300001), "Tier 1",
    IF(AND(B18 >= 100001, B18 < =300000, B19 >= 25, B19 <= 60), "Tier 2",
        IF(AND(B19 >= 0, B19 <= 100000, B18 <= 24), "Tier 3", "No Tier")))
```

Note that in the innermost/final `IF` call, I provided an else value of `No Tier`.  This is because there has to be an else value.  If you instead want everything which does not match tiers 1 and 2 to default to tier 3, then you can remove this final `IF` and just provide `Tier 3` as the else value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped me, but I miss represented my question.  What I need is a result of Tier 1, 2 or 3 depending on the two conditions. IF the requirements for tier 1 fail by one of the conditions then it should be 2 or 3. Does it make sense?